# $.ajax beforeSend not waiting for other ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous, xmlhttprequest

I have a jwt authentication system with a refreshToken.
Every 5 minutes the client browser has to request a new accessToken with the refreshToken saved in localStorage.

For that I'm using for every AJAX call I use a before send function.

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: addAuthHeader,
});

function addAuthHeader(xhr) {
   if(Math.round(new Date() / 1000) >= sessionStorage.getItem('jwt_exp')) {
        console.log('JWT expired. Refreshing now...');
        $.ajax({
            method: 'POST',
            url: '/auth/token/refresh',
            beforeSend: function (xhr) { },
            data: { token: localStorage.getItem('refreshToken') },
            // TODO: FIXME:  Synchronous are deprected
            async: false,
        }).done(function (data) {
            sessionStorage.setItem('jwt', data.accessToken);
            sessionStorage.setItem('jwt_exp', data.exp);

            xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + data.accessToken);
            console.log('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + data.accessToken);
        });
    } else {
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + sessionStorage.getItem('jwt'));
        console.log('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + sessionStorage.getItem('jwt'));
    }
}
```

As you can see I use a sync request now.
But these are deprecated:

```
[Deprecation] Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.
```

Is there anything I can do what I want asynchronous?
Running the second ajax call will not change the Headers => beforeSend isn't waiting till everything is completed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `beforeSend` attribute is fired right before the request is sent, but the request does not wait for it to finish. This is by design.

To create your functionality, i would wrap your requests in a special function, putting the request you want to go last in the .done function of the `addAuthHeader` request.

Something along the lines of:

```
function sendRequestWithAuth(requestFunction) {
   if(Math.round(new Date() / 1000) >= sessionStorage.getItem('jwt_exp')) {
        console.log('JWT expired. Refreshing now...');
        $.ajax({
            method: 'POST',
            url: '/auth/token/refresh',
            beforeSend: function (xhr) { },
            data: { token: localStorage.getItem('refreshToken') },
            // TODO: FIXME:  Synchronous are deprected
            async: false,
        }).done(function (data) {
            sessionStorage.setItem('jwt', data.accessToken);
            sessionStorage.setItem('jwt_exp', data.exp);

            xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + data.accessToken);
            console.log('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + data.accessToken);
            requestFunction();
        });
    } else {
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + sessionStorage.getItem('jwt'));
        console.log('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + sessionStorage.getItem('jwt'));
        requestFunction();
    }
}
```

This would make sure that your refresh request is sent and recieved before any function that is inserted into the `requestFunction()` callback gets executed.

To pass on the xhr.setRequestHeader, you can pass is as a parameter to the requestFunction like so: `requestFunction(data.accessToken);` or `requestFunction(sessionStorage.getItem('jwt'));` then insert the value to the request inside the function.

Answer (score 0):

JQuery [async: false] attribute you've used in your code is deprecated.

Try to work with async/await functions and call ajax like this:

```
async function fun() {
    ...
    await $.ajax({
        ...
```

It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

The other option is to cancel your request inside `beforeSend` (by returning `false`) and create a new request with your new headers. For example this works for me, and is automatically applied to all my requests without the need to call any wrapper:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function (xhr, settings)
    {
        firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken()
            .then(function(result) {
                $.ajax($.extend(settings, {
                    headers: {"X-Authorization-Firebase": result},
                    beforeSend: $.noop
                }));
            });
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: I'm trying to do something similar but I can't seem to trigger then `then`, `catch` and `always` callbacks from the original ajax call.